# How to create connection string that independent on instance and server name?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, connection-string

i want my application can run on every device that maybe have different server name and instance. my connection string is below:

```
DBDataContext db = new DBDataContext(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\App_data\DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=False");
```

Comment: Have you heard about config files?

Comment: No, it can help me ? please tell me how create connection string dynamically that find server name V11.0 and instance? or give me way to run my application on every computer. using c# and Sql server 2012.

Comment: i found reply for my question. its correctly connection string for SQL server 2012 or 2014. because in this version automatically instance and server name assigned beside  (LocalDB)\v11.0 . its dynamic connection string.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly and the Data Source is always on the local server, why don't you get the ip address of the server with System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"];

```
string myLocalserverIP = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"];
```

then use that in your Data Source string.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but how i retrieve LOCAL_ADDR? i just have to install MS SQL server Express 2014 on destination computer.  LOCAL_ADDR is enough? what i do for instance?